# Enabling token access to non-public Google Cloud Function

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I want to deploy a Google Cloud Function without public access. A service account should be able to invoke the function with least permissive rights - to be used by an external server.

I have created a service account, added bindings and downloaded keys:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts create <NAME> --project <PROJECT> --description <DESCRIPTION>
gcloud beta functions add-iam-policy-binding <FUNCTION> --region europe-west1 --member serviceAccount:<EMAIL> --role roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create --iam-account <EMAIL> <KEYFILE>
```

When I call the function with the invoker-role, this fails:

```sh
gcloud auth activate-service-account <EMAIL> --key-file <KEYFILE>
gcloud beta functions call <FUNCTION> --region=europe-west1 --data '{}'
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[The caller does not have permission]
```

However, when I switch to my user, add the `roles/cloudfunctions.developer` role, switch back to the service account, the above works:

```sh
gcloud config set account <USER>
gcloud beta functions add-iam-policy-binding <FUNCTION> --region europe-west1 --member serviceAccount:<EMAIL> --role roles/cloudfunctions.developer
gcloud auth activate-service-account <EMAIL> --key-file <KEYFILE>
gcloud beta functions call <FUNCTION> --region=europe-west1 --data '{}'
Success!
```

1. This really surprises me, I thought the invoker role should be sufficient. What am I missing here?

I wanted to use a token to access the function via curl, but this doesn't work at all, neither as invoker nor as developer:

```sh
echo $(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<KEYFILE> gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) > <TOKENFILE>
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat <TOKENFILE>" <FUNCTIONURL>
→ 401 Unauthorized as HTML page
```

2. What's the problem here?

Thanks for any help!
Best, Boris

Comment: FWIW ... I recreated your exact story and am also not understanding why invoker is not sufficient.

Comment: See below, it seems that `gcloud beta functions call ...` needs extra permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud recommends treating such requests as end-user requests i.e use OAuth2.0 by passing Authorization header(with bearer token) while accessing the Cloud functions with the invoker role. The details are [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers)

Try passing the bearer token by doing the following

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account <service account> <key file>
gcloud auth print-identity-token <service account>
curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME \
    -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

Comment: Great, that works! It also answers question #1: the developer role is required for calling the function with `gcloud beta functions cal ...`, but the invoker is sufficient with your version. Thanks!