# Google cloud (firebase) callable function 401: "unauthorized" error when called by http

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-iam

I have simple test callable function deployed via `firebase deploy --only functions`.

Here it's content:

```js
export const test = region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    logger.debug('test call info', data, context);
    return 'hello, world!';
});
```

I can successfully call it by doing HTTP call to `https://europe-west1-{project}.cloudfunctions.net/test` and recieve `{"result": "hello, world!"}`.

Now want to protect this function via IAM policies.

1. I create new service account and load it's credentials json.
2. I go to console and remove from `allUsers` a Cloud Functions Invoker role and add service account created in #1 with Cloud Functions Invoker role.
   <--- Now I recieve 403 Forbidden when I try to call my test function, as expected
3. I create id-token with my service account at my PC

```js
const auth = new GoogleAuth({keyFile: './key.json'});
targetAudience = new URL('https://europe-west1-{project}.cloudfunctions.net/test');
const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience as string);
const idToken = await client.idTokenProvider.fetchIdToken(targetAudience as string);
console.log(idToken);
```

4. I verify my token is correct and issued for the right service account via `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={{id-token}}`.
5. I call my endpoint with `Authorization: Bearer {{id-token}}` header.
6. I get 401 Unauthorized error with JSON telling me

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unauthenticated",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

7. I'm in pain since after reading most of google cloud docs, SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58742677/13737975), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026069/receiving-401-when-accessing-authenticated-google-cloud-function?rq=1)), etc. it seems that I do everything right but still get this error.

---

UPD1: providing additional info to @DazWilkin

1.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account cloud-functions-invoker@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file="key.json" 

Activated service account credentials for: [cloud-functions-invoker@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

2. 

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy {project-id}

...
- members:
  - serviceAccount:cloud-functions-admin@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:cloud-functions-invoker@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
...
```

3. I copy this value `gcloud auth print-identity-token | clip`
4. Here is what I get after calling `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={{id-token}}`

```
{
    "aud": "32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "azp": "cloud-functions-invoker@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "email": "cloud-functions-invoker@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "email_verified": "true",
    "exp": "1629157648",
    "iat": "1629154048",
    "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
    "sub": "114693730231812960252",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "6ef4bd908591f697a8a9b893b03e6a77eb04e51f",
    "typ": "JWT"
}
```

5. I make this curl (copied from postman). I've also tried same curl with command-line - got same result.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://europe-west1-{project-id}.cloudfunctions.net/test' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 
{token}
' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "data": {
        "goodbye": "world:("
    }
}'
```

---

UPD2: new input

This behaviour is observed only with *callable* functions `https.onCall()`. If I use `https.onRequest()` things work fine but I'm still confused about `onCall` behaviour, since it *seems* that I implement [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) correctly (see my curl).

Comment: It appears (!?) correct. You can use `gcloud` to [`gcloud auth print-identity-token` ](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token) after `gcloud auth activate-service-account@`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account). This will eliminate whether your client generation of the identity token is incorrect. Although your check using the endpoint does provide a good way to check.

Comment: You don't need to delete the existing account just add your newly created account to the IAM invoker role

Comment: Please show the `curl` (?) command in full that invokes the function and generates the 401

Comment: Perhaps include (edited) the result of `gcloud projects get-iam-policy` for the project to confirm the invoker binding.

Comment: @DazWilkin, thank you for your answer, really apprechiate. I've added info you requested to the question in the update section.

Comment: It should be `${token}` and must use double quotes `"` for the variable to be replaced with its value, i.e. if you `echo "authorization bearer: ${token}"`, you see the correct token replaced in the header.

Comment: IAM policy looks good!

Comment: If you're just using `{token}` in lieu of the value in your question, then I don't understand why it isn't working!

Comment: @DazWilkin, yea I was using `{token}` in lieu of the value. Even tho it didn't help, thank you for your effor to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @DazWilkin, so after further research, I've found out this thing happens only with _callable_ functions (see UPD2). It makes me think that something is wrong with the protocol. But it _seems_ that everything is ok with it. Maybe you have any idea?

Comment: I'm going to deploy a function myself today to see what happens

Comment: For some reason I missed that you're using Firebase not Cloud Functions. For Cloud Functions this works as you'd expect. I was unaware of the complexity in the equivalent Firebase function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OMG!!!!!

**TL;DR**: callable functions are only for *end users* authenticated with firebase auth and can't be used with IAM tokens. Only way to use them is with `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` assigned to `allUsers`.

---

The thing is... I was looking into *callable* functions protocol specification here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference.

It says:

> The HTTP request to a callable trigger endpoint must be a POST with the following headers:
>
> ...
>
> - Optional: Authorization: Bearer
>
>   - A Firebase Authentication user ID token for the logged-in user making the request. The backend automatically verifies this token and makes it available in the handler's context. If the token is not valid, the request is rejected.

I was thinking specification means that we shall pass our *service account* id-token here and I was trying to do so (such as with `onRequest` functions). BUT SUDDENLY, token is interpreted differently there. It's a user token which is obtained through firebase auth. And it's even stated in the documentation one level deeper ([1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens)):

> **Warning**: The ID token verification methods included in the Firebase Admin SDKs are meant to verify ID tokens that come from the client SDKs, not the custom tokens that you create with the Admin SDKs. See Auth tokens for more information.

Missing this warning costed me 3 days of pain.